# Rewrite rule is not working proper in IIS for phpfox

Tags: iis, url-rewriting, phpfox

**
I change my rewrite rule to change my website link from www.mydomain.com/index.php?do=/blog to www.mydomain.com/blog after this when i tried the below code, it won't let me change any page, like if i want to go for www.mydomain.com/blog, i just got stucked at www.mydomain.com, means redirect to my same root page,

what changes should i made for this please help. i am a newbei

my code is**

```
`<rule name="Redirect index.php" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="index\.php/(.*)" />
    <action type="Redirect" url="{R:1}" appendQueryString="false" />
  </rule>
  <rule name="Rewrite index.php">
    <match url="(.*)" />
    <conditions>
      <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
      <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php/{R:1}" />
  </rule>
</rules>`
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there any option in phpfox to set SEO friendly URL ?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18739871/is-there-any-option-in-phpfox-to-set-seo-friendly-url)

Answer (score 0):

Based on [this forum post](http://www.phpfox.com/forum/solved-cases-77/htaccess-2007/view_225193/) about `.htaccess` rewrites, you need to rewrite to:

`index.php?do=/{R:1}`

You are missing the `?do=` part in the middle.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <rewrite>
          <rules>
            <rule name="Imported Rule 1">
              <match url="^file/pic/photo/([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)/([A-Za-z0-9]{32}+)\-(.*?)_([0-9]*?)\.(.*)$" ignoreCase="false" />
              <action type="Rewrite" url="file/pic/photo/{R:1}/{R:2}/{R:3}_{R:5}.{R:6}" />
            </rule>
            <rule name="Imported Rule 2">
              <match url="^file/pic/photo/([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)/([A-Za-z0-9]{32}+)\-(.*?)\.(.*)$" ignoreCase="false" />
              <action type="Rewrite" url="file/pic/photo/{R:1}/{R:2}/{R:3}.{R:5}" />
            </rule>
            <rule name="Imported Rule 3">
              <match url="^(.*)$" ignoreCase="false" />
              <conditions>
                <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^www\." ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
              </conditions>
              <action type="Redirect" redirectType="Found" url="http://www.%" />
            </rule>
            <rule name="Imported Rule 4" stopProcessing="true">
              <match url="[^/]$" ignoreCase="false" />
              <conditions>
                <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
                <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
              </conditions>
              <action type="Redirect" redirectType="Permanent" url="{URL}/" />
            </rule>
            <rule name="Imported Rule 5">
              <match url="^(.*)" ignoreCase="false" />
              <conditions>
                <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
                <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
              </conditions>
              <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php?do=/{R:1}" appendQueryString="false" />
            </rule>
            <rule name="Imported Rule 6">
              <match url="^file/pic/photo/(.*)\.(.*)$" ignoreCase="false" />
              <action type="Rewrite" url="static/image.php?file={R:1}&amp;ext={R:2}" appendQueryString="false" />
            </rule>
          </rules>
        </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```